# How to send invitation mail for join a meeting in gotomeeting?

Tags: api, citrix

I have an account of gotomeeting and using api to create/start/getMeeting etc but I have not found any api to send mail and invite people to attend a meeting. Is it possible to send invitation mail to people to join a meeting using api? If not then is there any other solution to send meeting invitation mail?

Is it possible to register a user before start of meeting? How can we find how many user has attended the meeting?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, the email invitation will be in two type

1. A normal email from server
2. An appoinment item.

If you want to send a normal email to participants. just fill the mail with join **link** with Created **meetingid** 
You can create the join link for any particular meeting by concatenating the `www.global.gotomeeting.com/join/` with `meetingID` which is look like *www.global.gotomeeting.com/join/25456364* (number is sample meeting id).

send the above details as a mail. **Sending mails from program** depends on "which language you are developing" like C#/JAVA?

If you want to send the appoinment item, either you need to use EWS (Exchange webservices API) or you need to generate an ".ics" file from application with your meeting details filled in.

For your questions:

> 1. Is it possible to register a user before start of the meeting?

Yes, you can. the gotomeeting application itself having the options for invite a participant and adding a co-orrganizer.

> 2. How can we find how many user has attended the meeting?

You can find it using the api function call. below is the C# code for getting the attendees of a past meeting.

Namespace : `using Citrix.GoToMeeting.Api;`

```
MeetingsApi meeting = new MeetingsApi();
List<AttendeeByMeeting> attendees = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AttendeeByMeeting>();
attendees = meeting.getAttendeesByMeetings(accesToken, 23843894);
```

NOTE : API is used within the context of gotomeeting application, physically you cannot attend a meeting in any application except GotoMeeting desktop application and GotoMeeting webapplication (which is offered in their website).

Answer (score 0):

GTM isn't going to send the email for you it, as it doesn't have access to any email account. You should be looking to use one of the wide variety of different email APIs around. E.g. if you're in a Windows/Exchange environment then look at using the Exchange Web Services. If you want a more generic solution look for an SMTP library for your platform.

Attendees for GTMs don't register at any point, only hosts need to have a registered account. Even when you join a meeting as an attendee the details (name + email) you put in can be anything. What are you trying to achieve by "pre-registration"?

I can't answer your last question about finding out how many users attended the meeting, I would guess probably not but I'm not really familiar with the API.